# Linkedlist in C Programming

Tags: c, linked-list

I currently studying C and one of my practice is to create a linked list in C.

```
typedef struct deck
{
    int index;
    struct deck *next;
} decks;
```

My question is that why can't I create a new linked list as follows:(index, card after "=" is defined as variables)

```
decks* head = malloc(sizeof(decks));
decks* ptr = head;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  ptr -> index = i;
  ptr = ptr -> next;
  ptr = malloc(sizeof(decks));
}
```

Appreciate so much!

Comment: Because `ptr->next` is uninitialized and certainly not pointing to an existing memory block. Otherwise you wouldn't need the *first* `malloc` either.

Comment: what about now? @AnttiHaapala

Comment: so yes, now you'd at least have **11** objects, with 10 of them containing a number and none of them linked to the following, and 9 objects leaked. There is one shortest correct way to do this, then several longer ways to do a linked list and many incorrect ways to do a linked list and even more ways to try to do a linked list and fail at that... there are already dozens of QA existing on how to do it *correctly*...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Why these are leaked? As I have putted variable "head" and only move pointers

Comment: Please avoid modifying your question. It creates a moving target and makes all previous comments and answers useless.

Answer (score 3):

### Protip on debugging pointers

Draw pictures. Make a box for each instance and an arrow from each non-null pointer. ALWAYS follow the rules listed below. Assuming all memory management is done with `malloc` and `free` there are NO exceptions to these rules.

1. Every time and only when you do a `malloc` you should draw a new box.
2. Every time and only when you use `free` you should remove (or just cross it over with an X or something) a box.
3. Every time you use `free`, remove all arrows *from* that box.
4. Every time you assign a pointer to a value, null or non-null, remove the old arrow if it exists.
5. Every time and only when you assign a pointer to a non-null value, draw an arrow.

Note: For a typical call to `malloc`, you would use both rule 1, 4 and 5. Using `malloc` without taking care of the return pointer means leaking memory.

Note2: **Important!** You should NOT remove an arrow TO the box you're deallocating when you use `free`. Only do that when you specifically assign a pointer to null. In the same way, do NOT remove a box when you assign a pointer to null.

Note3: **Important!** If you free a box, rule 3 says that you should remove all arrows from that box. Do NOT remove any boxes the arrows are pointing to.

### Your question

Consider this:

```
ptr = ptr -> next;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(decks));
```

The first line has no effect whatsoever, since you are immediately reassigning `ptr`. 
You need something like this:

```
ptr -> next = malloc(sizeof(decks));
ptr = ptr -> next;
```

### Other remarks

I would recommend using sizeof on the variable rather than the type, like this: `ptr->next = malloc(sizeof *(ptr->next))` This is a good habit in general. Take this code:

```
int *x;
x = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Now consider if you want to change the type of the variable `x`. You would need to change the argument to `sizeof` in EVERY call to `malloc`. Using `x = malloc(sizeof *x)` completely removes this problem.

Comment: Appreciate a lot!

Comment: However what can I do if there are two types in the struct type not only integers?